# C# Regex that matches Excel file extensions

Tags: c#, excel, regex

I need a regex for my file upload to choose only Excel files I tried using this as my pattern(below)

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^.\.(xls|xlsx)");
```

Unfortunately I can't escape the "\." part of the the pattern.

Comment: have you tried this like

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374930/validating-file-types-by-regular-expression

Comment: @Ravi the problem im getting is the escape sequence for "."

Comment: Can you post full code

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A better method would be to use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx), then compare the results:

```
var filepath = @"C:\path\to\file.xls";
var extension = Path.GetExtension(filepath).ToUpper();

if (extension == ".XLS" || extension == ".XLSX") {
    // is an Excel file
}
```

---

To answer the original question, to match filepaths with`.xls` or `.xlsx` as a file extension, use the following regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@".*\.xlsx?$");
```

Comment: Instead of using ToUpper you could use Equals with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase instead, it's way clearer

Answer (score 5):

Just add another `\` or add the `@` in front of the string like so: `"^.\\.(xls|xlsx)"` or `@"^.\.(xls|xlsx)"`

Also, I am assuming that you shall be matching the extension of the file with that regex, and not the actual file name itself, since that regex will match anything which *starts* with `.xls` or `.xlsx`.