# PathPatternParser - Cannot combine patterns: *.csv and *.txt

Tags: spring

I have defined a SftpInboundFileSynchronizer class. I want to filter remote files which is of csv and txt files only. file extension array has *.csv and *.txt value

```
 SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new 
                     SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
 PathPatternParser pp = new PathPatternParser();
        PathPattern pattern = null;
 for(String fileExtension: fileExtensionArray) {
        if(pattern == null) {
            pattern = pp.parse(fileExtension);
        } else {
            pattern.combine(pp.parse(fileExtension));
        }
    }
   fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new 
        SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(pattern.getPatternString()));
```

The above throws the below exception

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot combine patterns: *.csv and *.txt
```

How to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: The `combine` is an `and` not an `or` and a file cannot be both *.csv and *.txt hence the failure. Instead of the `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter` you could use the regular expression based one.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please kindly share one link to refer?

Comment: Use [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/filters/SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter.html) class.

Comment: Thanks a lot and it works....new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter ("^.*\\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF)$"); (Another Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374930/validating-file-types-by-regular-expression)  - ^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF)$  and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-using-regular-expression/

Comment: You can answer to the question and close it. Thanks a lot @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PathPattern.combine` method will, as the name implies, combine the patterns. Basically making it an `and`. A file can never end in `.txt` and `.csv`. It must be an `or`. You cannot achieve this, afaik, with the `PathPattern`.

However with a regular expression that is fairly easy to do. Spring Integration ships with a component that can handle that for you. You can use the [`SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/filters/SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter.html) instead of the `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter`.

```java
SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter filter = new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter ("(?i)^.*\\.(csv|txt)$");
```

Something with the above expression should work (I'm not a pro on regular expressions, so it might need some work).