# How do I remove duplicated domains and invalid HTML files from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of urls. How do I remove the urls if it is not a valid html for example I want to remove pdf/jpy files and also want to remove duplicated domains.

```
example_list = [
'https://ocp.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/ocp/publication/attachments/Report-of-Contracting-Activity-Part-I.pdf', 
'https://the1955club.com/', 
'https://the1955club.com/aboutus']
```

so in the new list it should return the below

```
new_list = ['https://the1955club.com/']
```

Comment: you could use `urllib.parse` to split url into parts and keep urls which don't have anything after domain. Eventually you can `split('/')` and keep urls which have only 3 pasts (or 4 parts but last is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check both the url and the file path, if it finds a repeated URL or a bad filepath (ending with .pdf, .jpeg, etc.) it will ignore it.

```
import re

valid_domains = set()

example_list = [
'https://ocp.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/ocp/publication/attachments/Report-of-Contracting-Activity-Part-I.pdf', 
'https://the1955club.com/', 
'https://the1955club.com/aboutus'
'http://the1955club.com']

print()

for example in example_list:
    res = re.search('(http[s]??:\/\/.+?)(\/.*)', example)
    extension = re.findall('^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF|jpy|JPY)$', res.group(2)) # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374930/validating-file-types-by-regular-expression
    if res.group(1) in valid_domains or len(extension):
        continue

    valid_domains.add(res.group(1))
    
print(valid_domains)
```

Ouput:

```
 {'https://the1955club.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: in Python it is better to create new list with elements which you want to keep and later assign it to old variable.

---

You can use `urllib.parse.urlparse(url)` to split url and check if `.path` is `""` or `"/"`

```
import urllib.parse

example_list = [
    'https://ocp.dc.gov/sites/default/files/dc/sites/ocp/publication/attachments/Report-of-Contracting-Activity-Part-I.pdf', 
    'https://the1955club.com/', 
    'https://the1955club.com/aboutus'
]

new_list = []

for url in example_list:
    parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    if parts.path in ("", "/"):
        new_list.append(url)
        
example_list = new_list

print(example_list)
```

---

**EDIT:**

But if you want to filter urls which really are not valid then you may need to use `requests` and try to get this url. If you don't get result then url is wrong.